# Forwarding incoming calls to Skype/VOIP

Tags: voip, skype, forwarding

I have googled and searched all over the forums etc for this, but I only ever come up with 'how to port your Skype number to Twilio' etc...

I need to have incoming calls to my Twilio numbers, forwarded to my Skype account so that I can answer form my phone (with the skype app), OR forwarded to any android (or even Computer) based application so that I can answer the incoming call to Twilio myself to treat it like a normal call, on the go...

Sorry for being completely new to all this!

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 1):

Get pbxes.com - then twilio can forward to your sip uri there, and your phone REGISTER's itself to pbxes.com to receive the call.